# How to get rid of from SpreadOperator performance warning that was given by Detekt while using Spring Boot?

Tags: java, spring, kotlin, detekt

Recently, I added [Detekt](https://github.com/arturbosch/detekt) analyzer to my application.

After I runned detekt (./gradlew detekt), I got SpreadOperator warning in my main class of application.

Warning on code: `runApplication<MessCallsApplication>(*args)`

You can read about SpreadOperator warning here: [`SpreadOperator Warning`](https://arturbosch.github.io/detekt/performance.html)

my main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = [RedisAutoConfiguration::class])
@EnableCircuitBreaker
@EnableScheduling
class MyApplication {

    companion object : KLogging()
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler { _, exception ->
        MessCallsApplication.logger.error(exception) { "Uncaught exception" }
    }

    runApplication<MessCallsApplication>(*args)
}
```

Question is, What is the best practice to get rid of from that SpreadOperator warning? Or is it impossible?

Answer (score 11):

In your particular case:

```kotlin
 runApplication<MessCallsApplication>(args = args)
```

Edit:

This detekt warning is not longer a case:
https://github.com/detekt/detekt/pull/3157

However as Klitos Kyriacou mentioned in code - this array is copied (even twice!). Decompiled bytecode:

```java
public final class MessCallsApplicationKt {
   public static final void main(@NotNull String[] args) {
      Intrinsics.checkNotNullParameter(args, "args");
      Schedulers.enableMetrics();
      String[] args$iv = (String[])Arrays.copyOf(args, args.length);
      int $i$f$runApplication = false;
      Intrinsics.checkExpressionValueIsNotNull(SpringApplication.run(MessCallsApplication.class, (String[])Arrays.copyOf(args$iv, args$iv.length)), "SpringApplication.run(T::class.java, *args)");
   }
}
```

Comment: Looking at the generated bytecode, I could see that using named parameters also copies the array, the same way as using the spread operator. However, I guess this is something the static code analyser is unaware of and doesn't give you a warning.

Comment: Yes, I updated the answer to reflect your findings :)

Answer (score 8):

You can add `@Suppress("SpreadOperator")` before your expression like this:

```
@SpringBootApplication(exclude = [RedisAutoConfiguration::class])
@EnableCircuitBreaker
@EnableScheduling
class MyApplication {

    companion object : KLogging()
}

fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    Thread.setDefaultUncaughtExceptionHandler { _, exception ->
        MessCallsApplication.logger.error(exception) { "Uncaught exception" }
    }
    @Suppress("SpreadOperator")
    runApplication<MessCallsApplication>(*args)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

or simply change from:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>)
```

to

```
fun main(vararg args: String)
```

Comment: This doesn't work: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64260146

Answer (score 0):

you have to pass the * to the run method:

```
fun main(vararg args: String) {
  runApplication<RateRefresherApplication>(*args)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this in a function call like this:

```
private fun combine(vararg messages: String){ . . . }

...

//elsewhere
combine(*messages)
```

In my particular case, it made sense to change the signature of this to the following (because it was intended to process a vararg from another function, rather than accept a comma-separated list, itself).

This uses with the `vararg` parameter as an array, rather than converting it into yet another variable argument:

```
private fun combine(messages: Array<out String>){ . . . }

...

//elsewhere
combine(messages) // now can remove spread operator
```