# Why Kotlin main vararg args: String cannot be directly passed to SpringBoot's runApplication?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin

I wanted to check if I can avoid using the spread operator when starting a SpringBoot application.

So, instead of the usual:

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    runApplication<Application>(*args)
}
```

This is what I tried:

```
fun main(vararg args: String) {
    runApplication<Application>(args)
}
```

But I saw that this doesn't work. I was getting an error telling me that runApplication requires a `String` but it found an `Array<out String>`. And suggested me to use *args, which is precisely what I was trying to avoid.

None of this makes sense to me since `args` is actually a vararg type and not just a String. And also by looking at the definition of SpringBoot's runApplication I see:

```
public inline fun <reified T : kotlin.Any> runApplication(vararg args: kotlin.String): org.springframework.context.ConfigurableApplicationContext { /* compiled code */ }
```

which decompiled is:

```
public static final ConfigurableApplicationContext runApplication(@NotNull String... args) {...}
```

and I assume `vararg args: String` is the equivalent to Java's `String...`

Does anyone have an explanation for this? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [documentation](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/functions.html) provides this example:

```
fun <T> asList(vararg ts: T): List<T> {
    val result = ArrayList<T>()
    for (t in ts) // ts is an Array
        result.add(t)
    return result
}
```

And states:

> Inside a function a vararg-parameter of type T **is visible as an array of T**, i.e. the ts variable in the example above has type **Array<out T>**

From this we can see that a vararg is transformed into an Array inside the function that receives it. Hence you can only propagate that to `runApplication` only by expanding it with `*`.

Also you said that:

> and I assume vararg args: String is the equivalent to Java's String...

You assumed correctly, it is the equivalent, but that does not mean it is identical.

Kotlin does this to resolve an ambiguity that Java creates. For example if you have an `Object...` parameter and you pass it a single array of type `Array<Fizz>`. Should the compiler read that as a single object of type `Array<Fizz>` or as multiple arguments of type `Fizz`?

In Kotlin, you distinguish those two cases by giving (or not giving) the spread operator *

Answer (score 0):

```java
fun main(vararg args: String) {
    println(args::class.java)
    runApplication<Application>(*args)
}
```

prints:
`class [Ljava.lang.String;`

Seams like java array can not be passed to kotlin's vararg